# Dojo Query returns undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to get a DOM element by class and not sure why its returning undefined. I can query the parent element without any problems. Here is my code:

```
        var contentPane = query('.contentPane', this.map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];
        var header = query('.header', this.map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];

        console.log(header);
        console.log(contentPane);
```

The output in console:

```
>>undefined

<div class="contentPane">
  <div class="esriViewPopup" id="esri_dijit__PopupRenderer_1" widgetid="esri_dijit__PopupRenderer_1">
    <div class="mainSection">
      <div class="header" dojoattachpoint="_title"></div>
      <div class="hzLine"></div>
      <div dojoattachpoint="_description"></div>
      <div class="break"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="attachmentsSection hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="mediaSection hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="editSummarySection hidden" dojoattachpoint="_editSummarySection">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've not used dojo, so I'm not best placed to answer, but does adding some content into that .header node make any difference?

Comment: `contentPane` is part of `infoWindow`, whereas, header section is created dynamically. depending on when you are quering, it could be undefined. Could you setup a fiddler to show how you are querying or share more code.

Comment: `.header` is part of a subwidget. That mean `.header` is in the dom only after parsing and creating the subwidget `esri_dijit__PopupRenderer_1`. Chanc are that you `query` it before the render

Comment: thanks everyone. your answers were all on the right track. the header was not rendered at the time of query. I have resolved this by using`query` when the function was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.header` was not rendered at the time of query. I have resolved this by using `query` when the containing function was completed.